# Functional Alternative to Game Loop

Tags: scala, functional-programming, game-loop

I'm just starting out with the Scala and am trying a little toy program - in this case a text based TicTacToe.  I wrote a working version based on what I know about scala, but noticed it was mostly imperative and my classes were mutable.

I'm going through and trying to implement some functional idioms and have managed to at least make the classes representing the game state immutable.  However, I'm left with a class responsible for performing the game loop relying on mutable state and imperative loop as follows:

```
  var board: TicTacToeBoard = new TicTacToeBoard

  def start() {
    var gameState: GameState = new XMovesNext
    outputState(gameState)
    while (!gameState.isGameFinished) {
      val position: Int = getSelectionFromUser
      board = board.updated(position, gameState.nextTurn)
      gameState = getGameState(board)
      outputState(gameState)      
    }
  }
```

What would be a more idiomatic way to program what I'm doing imperatively in this loop?

Full source code is here https://github.com/whaley/TicTacToe-in-Scala/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/jasonwhaley/tictactoe

Comment: You can grab some inspiration from Vasil Remeniuk's [Tic-Tac-Toe API with phantom types](http://vasilrem.com/blog/software-development/tic-tac-toe-api-with-phantom-types/) article.

Comment: @4e6 +1'ed and I'm going to hold on to that link for later.  There are features of scala I'm not familiar with at all right now discussed in that post (traits, and how scala handles type parameters).  I'll start from scratch maybe using this post as a springboard when ready.  Thanks!

Comment: One problem with stack overflow is you can't accept multiple answers.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: While it is great that you're concerned about side effects like mutable state it is worth remembering that every useful program must change the "state of the world" apart from turning electric energy into heat. Hence, it is ok to have move output, move input and a board state. Just make sure that everything else will not interfere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement it as a recursive method. Here's an unrelated example:

```
object Guesser extends App {
  val MIN = 1
  val MAX = 100

  readLine("Think of a number between 1 and 100. Press enter when ready")

  def guess(max: Int, min: Int) {
    val cur = (max + min) / 2
    readLine("Is the number "+cur+"? (y/n) ") match {
      case "y" => println("I thought so")
      case "n" => {
        def smallerGreater() { 
          readLine("Is it smaller or greater? (s/g) ") match {
            case "s" => guess(cur - 1, min)
            case "g" => guess(max, cur + 1)
            case _   => smallerGreater()
          }
        }
        smallerGreater()
      }
      case _   => {
        println("Huh?")
        guess(max, min)
      } 
    }
  }

  guess(MAX, MIN)
}
```

Comment: I reimplemented it as a recursive function and that works fine.  I guess I should just trust that scalac will detect it and do TCO.

Comment: @whaley, trust but [verify](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.tailrec) ;)

Comment: @whaley I don't see why an implementation of Tic Tac Toe would need to be tail-call optimized

Comment: @LuigiPlinge it wouldn't at all, but if this were a game that ran the "game loop" indefinitely then it would

Answer (score 7):

imho for Scala, the imperative loop is just fine. You can always write a recursive function to behave like a loop. I also threw in some pattern matching.

```
def start() {
    def loop(board: TicTacToeBoard) = board.state match {
        case Finished => Unit
        case Unfinished(gameState) => {
             gameState.output()
             val position: Int = getSelectionFromUser()
             loop(board.updated(position))
        }
    }

    loop(new TicTacToeBoard)
}
```

Suppose we had a function `whileSome : (a -> Option[a]) a -> ()`, which runs the input function until its result is None. That would strip away a little boilerplate.

```
def start() {
    def step(board: TicTacToeBoard) = {
        board.gameState.output()
        val position: Int = getSelectionFromUser()
        board.updated(position) // returns either Some(nextBoard) or None
    }

    whileSome(step, new TicTacToeBoard)
}
```

`whileSome` should be trivial to write; it is simply an abstraction of the former pattern. I'm not sure if it's in any common Scala libs, but in Haskell you could grab `whileJust_` from [monad-loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html).

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
Stream.continually(processMove).takeWhile(!_.isGameFinished)
```

where `processMove` is a function that gets selection from user, updates board and returns new state.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something with how Stream.continually and Stream.takeWhile are meant to work.  Using this technique doesn't allow me to keep repeating processMove while my isGameFinished is false. In fact, it only performs processMove once no matter if my predicate passed in to takeWhile returns true or false.  Code was updated on github to reflect attempt.

Comment: Would `takeWhile` build up a very large list? Or does the Scala compiler recognize that the stream elements are unused?

Comment: @whaley I see you're creating _continually_ new boards! Maybe you should declare a `val board = new TicTacToeBoard` and pass it to `processMove` (or even better, make `processMove` a method of `TicTacToeBoard`). Take into account that `continually` defers parameter evaluation ([call by name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name)), as its parameter type is `=> A`.

Comment: @DanBurton `Stream` is a lazy list, so it can be infinite. I think to make this solution properly functional you would need a recursive definition of the Stream, so that the state of the previous move is an input into the next one. If you use `continually` you'd have to rely on external `var`s.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge I can't see if `continually` really fits without starting to code right now. But I see the whole picture pretty simple: create a `BoardState` inmutable class (each instance is one of the possible states) and a function `(BoardState, UserInput) => BoardState`, then the application is just the generation of a `BoardState`s sequence driven by a stream of `UserInputs` and the function.

Comment: `Stream.iterate` would more adequately express the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the recursive version, but here's a proper implementation of the `Stream` version:

var board: TicTacToeBoard = new TicTacToeBoard

```
def start() {
  def initialBoard: TicTacToeBoard = new TicTacToeBoard
  def initialGameState: GameState = new XMovesNext
  def gameIterator = Stream.iterate(initialBoard -> initialGameState) _
  def game: Stream[GameState] = {
    val (moves, end) = gameIterator {
      case (board, gameState) =>
        val position: Int = getSelectionFromUser
        val updatedBoard = board.updated(position, gameState.nextTurn)
        (updatedBoard, getGameState(board))
    }.span { case (_, gameState) => !gameState.isGameFinished }
    (moves ::: end.take(1)) map { case (_, gameState) => gameState }
  }
  game foreach outputState
}
```

This looks weirder than it should. Ideally, I'd use `takeWhile`, and then `map` it afterwards, but it won't work as the *last* case would be left out!

If the moves of the game could be discarded, then `dropWhile` followed by `head` would work. If I had the side effect (`outputState`) instead the `Stream`, I could go that route, but having side-effect inside a `Stream` is way worse than a `var` with a `while` loop.

So, instead, I use `span` which gives me both `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` but forces me to save the intermediate results -- which can be real bad if memory is a concern, as the whole game will be kept in memory because `moves` points to the head of the `Stream`. So I had to encapsulate all that inside another method, `game`. That way, when I `foreach` through the results of `game`, there won't be anything pointing to the `Stream`'s `head`.

Another alternative would be to get rid of the *other* side effect you have: `getSelectionFromUser`. You can get rid of that with an `Iteratee`, and then you can save the last move and reapply it.

OR... you could write yourself a [`takeTo`](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2963) method and use that.